# Azure app insights not displaying SQL command text

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-application-insights

I have two versions of an ASP.NET Core app running in Azure (RC1 and RC2). RC1 app shows EF Core SQL commands text in app insights but RC2 does not. I tried  deployment for different frameworks (net452, net46, netcoreapp1.0) - no luck.

I successfully installed AI extension to the RC2 app and my custom dependencies are tracked.

What am I missing?

Comment: To clarify, when you say AI Extension, you mean Azure Application Insights extension for WebApps?

Comment: Yep, the one you install in tools/extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug. Here is the announcement [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/12)